# How to tell git there is nothing to merge?

Tags: git, permissions, git-merge

I removed the execute bit from `*.h` and `*.cpp` files. I committed the changed and tried to push them. The machine I was working on does not have my SSH keys, so the push failed.

I did the same on a different machine with the SSH keys, and I was able to commit and push the changes. I needed to use [Updating file permissions only in git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21071387/608639) however, because Git did not observe or recognize the changed file permissions.

Now, I'm back on the original machine. I performed a `git pull`, but its refusing to take the changes:

```
$ git pull
remote: Counting objects: 2, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 2 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (2/2), done.
From https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp
   4206b4a..f03ab5c  master     -> origin/master
Updating 4206b4a..f03ab5c
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    cpu.cpp
    cpu.h
    cryptlib_bds.cpp
    emsa2.cpp
    emsa2.h
    salsa.cpp
    salsa.h
    serpentp.h
    sosemanuk.cpp
    sosemanuk.h
    vmac.cpp
    vmac.h
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

Apparently, git is too dumb to realize that the file permission is 0644 locally and 0644 remotely, so there is nothing to do.

How do I tell git there is nothing to merge?

Comment: Did you try the usual `git stash; git pull; git stash apply`?

Comment: @DarkFalcon - I committed them on both machines.

Comment: If you committed on both machines, git wouldn;t be complaining about local changes being overwritten. It would complain about a merge conflict

Comment: @DarkFalcon - thanks. How do I tell Git to take the changes because there's nothing to merge? The changes are the same on both machines.

Comment: With the steps above. Stash all local changes, pull, then apply the stashed changes (which will merge).

Answer (score 0):

If you really think there are no changes on your local box you want to preserve, a `git checkout .` will undo your local "changes," and you can then pull. Or, if git thinks your changes have been added to the index, a `git reset --hard HEAD` will blow everything away. I would play it safe, though, and do a `git stash` instead. This way any changes you didn't realize you had will at least be accessible.

Comment: Yes, I had to `git update-index --chmod=-x *.h *.cpp`. I want to avoid the `git reset --hard HEAD` because I am working on a patch, so other files have changed. Is it not possible to tell Git to take the remote changes because there are no differences in what its complaining about?