# GIT change file permission to 775 (not 755) how?

Tags: git, permissions, chmod

In Git, all i found out to change the file/folder permissions is to `755` (with: +x) only. Which is:

```
$ git update-index --chmod=+x docroot/myfolder
```

How do i then change it to:

- 775
- 777

etc, as i like?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10516406/5241514

Take a look at this and you'll know how to do it LOL

Comment: No, it doesn't show how to change to any specific permission i want. (And i already have that options turned on)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am a little late, but:

As far as I know, git stores only "executable" or "not executable".  If a file is marked as executable, it will be checked out with permissions something like 777.  If you execute `umask 0002` before checkout, you get file permissions 775.

Before all of this, you might want to execute `umask` without parameters.  It will return the current settings, so you are able to restore them later.

This might be an answer to your question.  But I don't know, if I would recommend these commands ;)