# portable shell script that can be run from npm run

Tags: node.js, bash, npm

If I have a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o errexit # Exit on error

cd /blah
do stuff...
```

I need to use chmod to set the script and everybody who pulls form the repo will have to do the same.

Is there a way to make this portable without having to set permissions?

Comment: Are you using Git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can set the file permissions so when it is pulled back it has them set still. See [Updating file permissions only in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516201/updating-file-permissions-only-in-git)