# Failed to Discard Changes

Tags: github, github-desktop

I am currently using github desktop. I tried to discard changes to one of the edited files before making a commit. Github returned 'Failed to discard changes' This file may be in use by another application. (I closed all related applications beforehand).

Any clues as to what could be causing this?

Comment: try restarting the app

Comment: I restarted the app. Logged out. Also restarted my computer. No luck.

Comment: I hope this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575682/cant-seem-to-discard-changes-in-git

Comment: As of now (September 2017), the error message I received after attempting to discard local changes was, "The file couldn’t be saved."

Answer (score 10):

Faced the same problem on Github Desktop, tried a lot of things, but finally got issue fixed by running the following commands from powershell.

`git rm --cached -r .
git reset --hard`

Make sure, you save any uncommitted local changes before running those.

Comment: This temporarily fixed things for me in that it discarded my uncommitted local changes but I'm still unable to discard changes via the GitHub App